# Persisting an associated detached entity by cascade in Spring Data Jpa. Is it possible?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

What if I want to persist a "new" entity with an "old" associated entity in Spring Data Jpa? Let me show you what I mean

1. Signup request comes in, here's how I handle it

```java
    public Mono<ServerResponse> signUp(ServerRequest request) {
        return request.bodyToMono(UserDto.class)
                .map(userMapper::toUser)
                .map(userService::encodePassword)
                .map(userService::addDefaultRoles)
                .map(userService::save)
                .map(this::toAuthenticatedUpat)
                .map(tokenService::generateTokenFor)
                .transform(jwt -> ServerResponse.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(jwt, String.class));
    }
```

The important parts are `addDefaultRoles()` and `save()`

```java
    @Override
    public User save(User user) {
        return userRepository.save(user); // Spring Data's repository
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional // the only @Transactional method in UserServiceImpl
    public User addDefaultRoles(User user) {
        Optional<Role> userRoleOptional = roleService.findByAuthority(Role.USER);
        Role userRole = userRoleOptional.orElse(new Role(Role.USER));
        userRole.addUser(user);
        user.addRole(userRole);
        return user;
    }
```

```java
// @Entity etc.
public class User implements UserDetails {
// ...
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST) // note this
    @JoinTable(name = "users_roles",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private Set<Role> authorities;
```

```java
// @Entity etc.
public class Role implements GrantedAuthority {
    public static final String USER = "user";
    // ...
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "authorities")
    private Set<User> users;
```

2. Suppose I have a clean slate, and the database doesn't have any records. A first signup request completes fine: `userRoleOptional` is empty, and both the new user and the new `USER` role are persisted

```java
// Spring's SimpleJpaRepository

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public <S extends T> S save(S entity) {

        Assert.notNull(entity, "Entity must not be null");

        if (entityInformation.isNew(entity)) { // true
            entityManager.persist(entity); // persist cascaded to role
            return entity;
        } else {
            return entityManager.merge(entity);
        }
    }
```

3. Then a second signup request comes in. This time, I have a new user and an old role (`USER`). `entityInformation.isNew(entity)` is evaluated to `true`, again, `persist()` is invoked and cascaded to the role which is *now deemed detached*, and this happens

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.example.tokenservice.data.entity.Role
```

How do I avoid this?

Comment: Though I'm still in the process of figuring out at what point it got detached. I didn't `evict()` it, did I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My conclusion is:

1. Persisting a detached entity throws no matter what
2. Spring Data's `if` check will evaluate to `true` no matter what (if you persist a new entity)
3. Cascade persisting of the role won't go through the same check since it will bypass the Spring Data framework
4. Meaning `save()`ing a new entity with an associated detached entity will inevitably throw

Here's a workaround. Remove the cascade...

```java
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "users_roles",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private Set<Role> authorities;
```

...and persist the role beforehand (if it doesn't exist yet) *manually*

```java
    @Override
    @Transactional
    public User addDefaultRoles(User user) {
        Optional<Role> userRoleOptional = roleService.findByAuthority(Role.USER);
        Role userRole = userRoleOptional.orElseGet(() -> roleService.save(new Role(Role.USER)));
        userRole.addUser(user);
        user.addRole(userRole);
        return user;
    }
```